# Exim can't send email (unable to set gid or uid forcing real = effective)

Tags: php, debian, sendmail, exim

I've a debian Jessie and Exim4. I can't send email from php, error given is:
unable to set gid=33 or uid=0 (euid=0): forcing real = effective

I've tried to search for this problem but nothing helps me.

One solution found was to add trusted_user in exim configuration, but not works either

Someone can help me?

Comment: I've solved, I've setted LimitUIDRange 0 2000 in mpm_prefork.con an apache module.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by switching to Event from prefork on a WHM server running EasyApache 4:

```
yum shell

remove ea-apache24-mod_mpm_prefork

remove ea-apache24-mod_cgid

install ea-apache24-mod_mpm_event

install ea-apache24-mod_cgi

run

quit
```